# R: avoid abline to automatically draw a horizontal line through my 0 point

Tags: r, graph

My goal is to make vertical dotted grid lines every 5 ticks of my x axis of my existing plot.

The command I use is:

```
abline(h=FALSE,v=seq(0,40,by=5),col="gray",lty=3)
```

The result is exactly what I need except for a horizontal line at my 0 position that my command creates. The y axis goes from -20 to +20. Any ideas?

Comment: h=NULL should fix it, FALSE gets converted to a numeric value of zero

Comment: and as `h=NULL` is the default value, you can just do `abline(v=seq(0,40,by=5),col="gray",lty=3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the help file for `?abline` we see that horizontal lines will be plotted at the values of `h`. `FALSE` gets converted to a numeric value of zero, hence the line that you've got at y=0. To fix this, use the code:

```
plot(-10:50, rnorm(61)) #to create a plot
abline(h=NULL,v=seq(0,40,by=5),col="gray",lty=3)
```

As @CathG mentions in the comments, this is the default, so you can simply omit the `h` argument to get:

```
abline(v=seq(0,40,by=5),col="gray",lty=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

as Miff and CathG answered in the comments :

setting h=NULL fixed it.

Thank you very much!
(p.s. Miff if you´d post an answer I´d accept it so you get credit for it)